# Show cell with criteria using IF formula, Index and Match

Tags: excel, wps

[image]

I want to have a plan and actual for daily from the table given above.
For example, If today is 3rd May, i want it to show only data from 3 May. Is this possible, i have tried working around with If, index and match but cant seem to work.

Comment: Show what you have tried - maybe we can correct what did not work. However do check on here because similar has been done before.

Comment: Also if you post data that can be copied then we don't have to waste our time retyping it.

Comment: Per Solar Mike's comment, use markdown tables - I recommend tablesgenerator.com to make it easy for you

Comment: alright SolarMike and Spencer Barnes, Will do that next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming both the dates in table headers and the date you are looking up are both actual dates, you can do it this way:

Formula for the "Plan" column:

```
=INDEX($1:$11,A18*2,MATCH($C$15,$1:$1,0))
```

Formula for the "Actual" column:

```
=INDEX($1:$11,A18*2+1,MATCH($C$15,$1:$1,0))
```

Put these in B18 and C18 respectively and expand down.

Changing the date in C15 will update the table below with the data from table above.

[image]